# How to backup all the iso and config files

Tags: backup, hp

We have:
Existing Spec:
Model: HP Proliant DL380p Gen 8 Server
Processor: 2 x Intel® Xeon® E5-2650 v2 (2.6GHz/8-core)
Memory: 32GB (2 x 16GB)
HDD: 1TB SAS Hot-Plug HDD

We are Upgrading it to:
Memory: 32GB (2 x 16GB)
HDD: 1TB SAS Hot-Plug HDD

Now, my question is how can i backup all the files and data that is already in the single hard disk. We want to add the hard disk and still make it in RAID 0. 
I read somewhere that if we don't have L3 cache, we can't add a new hard disk to existing config online. Is it true?

We are running EXSI and there are 4 clients running now.

What i need is i want to add the new hard drive, increase the memory and i don't want my data to get lost. 
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

> ... i don't want my data to get lost

The normal way to do this is to use a backup system that is compatible with your OS.

1. Choose a backup system
2. Perform backups
3. Verify backups
4. Perform hardware upgrade

Comment: So you mean i can't do that online?? I can't just plug the new hard disk and the system performs the upgrade? Does that happen?